# How to center an hidden/visible element so it always shows up in the middle of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image can be show and hidden by an button. How do I style the image so it always shows up in the middle of the users screen. I work with position:absoulte;!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: middle of the screen => `position: fixed`. `position: absolute` will align it out of flow to the next relative element which by default will be the body. As long as the body height is not exactly 100vh you will not be able to align it to the center of the screen that way.

Comment: Is the image a sort of background image or is it to be in front of other stuff on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need position fixed not absolute to get it centered on the viewport rather than on the body.

But you also need to make sure the the img is not a child of another transformed etc. element beneath body otherwise it will position fixed to that. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Here's a simple example of making sure the img is centered on the viewport:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  img.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20vw;
}

img.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
<button>Click to hide/unhide the image</button>
```

Note that there are several ways of hiding an element: display none which removes it more or less entirel; visibility hidden which keeps the space it was occupying - though in this case it does not matter in the way it would if the element were not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For proper alignment of an element, i would suggest u use a flexbox.

This enables proper vertical and horizontal alignment, so you can at last easily center your element.

To center an element with flexbox we use the `align-items` for vertical alignment and `justify-content` for horizontal alignment.

Take a look at an example below.

```js
// Select element with querySelector() method which returns the first element that matches a CSS selector.
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// The addEventListener method attaches an event handler to an element (button).
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  img.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.img-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btnClick{
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200">
  </div> 
  <button class="btnClick">Click to show/hide image</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to center an element with `position: absolute`.

Here is how you can do that:

```css
.some-element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: this will align the elemnt to the center of the next relative parent which will nto necessarily be the screen (viewport).